# How can I pick the correct replacement usb charger for my phone?

Tags: usb, charging

My phone has a wall charger with outputs 5vdc and 850mA, which just broke (I saved the USB-microB cable which I've been using to charge from laptops). Unfortunately, OEM chargers of that particular model are not readily available in our area. So, I have to resort to generic/replacement chargers or adapters. Now, when I got to an electronics store, they don't have a charger with the exact specs. It's either a 700mA or an iPhone adapter that has 1A output current. Which should be somehow better/safe for my phone which has Li-Ion 1320 mAh battery? I've seen other threads which suggest getting higher outputs while some say otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Jerikj! Please note that shopping recommendations are off topic here. You might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: I think this question is fine here. He's not asking about what to buy or where, but what to look for when buying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a higher current charger will not be a problem.  The phone "pulls" current, rather than having the current "pushed" to it by the charger, so it will only take as much current as it wants, regardless of how much the charger is capable of supplying.

By relation, there's no point in getting a charger with a current rating higher than your phone will accept.  It's just a waste of money, as your phone won't make use of the extra capability.  Exactly how much current your phone will accept is usually unspecified and is generally only determinable by direct measurement (i.e. put a multimeter in the circuit), and thus generally isn't practical to exactly determine for an everyday user.

1A chargers are fairly standard and would be completely adequate for almost any phone.  Chargers with more current than that are generally intended for tablets/phablets which have much larger batteries and will accept more current (e.g. 10" tablets generally charge at around 2.5A).  Your phone will charge off those fine, but as I said above, just won't take advantage of the extra current capability you paid for.

Comment: ok. Got it. but, in terms of keeping the battery itself in tiptop condition or the chances of preventing damage to the phone (well, because its just a replacement). can I assume the charger with lower current is "safer" than the higher current charger? or both will be no problem for the phone?

Comment: Neither will be a problem.  As I said, the phone will only take as much current as it wants, regardless of how much the charger can supply.  Whether the charger is just capable of supplying the peak charge current or whether the charger could supply enough current to light up Manhattan will make no difference, the phone will pull the exact same amount from it.

Answer (score 1):

The 700mA is safer bet but will result in longer charging period than the 1A/850mA. 
The 1A charger would be charging faster but might not be preferable (check your battery for the details Voltage & Current).

PS: Incompatible chargers tend to cause weird *ghost touches* in the touch screen.